# Why does silicon have an indirect gap?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is there an intuitive explanation as to why silicon has an indirect gap? I have heard that this can explained using pseudopotentials.

Comment: There is no intuitive explanation of experimental facts like this one. Actually, this is hard to get even from first-principle calculations.